# Problem from and problem with

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

Let's say your network subscriber is GLOBE, then inexplicably, you lost connection which unables you to go online. And you say:

> ''There is a network **problem from** GLOBE itself at the moment and is not a device issue, that is why I can't surf the net.

Or

> "There is a network **problem with** GLOBE services itself at the moment and is not a device issue, that is why I can't surf the net.

Are they correctly phrased?

Comment: This US English speaker would always say "problem **with**".  *From* implies something like "coming from one place to another", but the problem is not moving, it just *is*.

Comment: The problem was from the GLOBE-side of the network, not from the customer side. But: there is a problem with, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that you gave, "problem with" would be the correct choice, because you are talking about the ***cause*** of a problem. If there is a thing that is causing a problem for you, then you have a "*problem with*" that thing.

There are other contexts where "*problem from*" is correct, though. For example, if you were talking to a friend about a math problem in a book, you might say:

> Did you finish that difficult **problem from** Chapter 2?

In this case you use "from" because you are talking about ***where*** you encountered the math problem.

Another time you might see "problem from" would be if you were talking about a problem that spanned a certain time period, and were talking about when it began. For example:

> The leaky roof was only a **problem from** November through March,
>   during the rainy season.

Here, you say "*from*" to indicate ***when*** the problem begins.